# Passing responses from one PsychoPy routine to another

Tags: psychopy

I am trying to send the value of a response time (e.g. key_resp_2.rt) to a later routine.

I am new to PsychoPy and am unsure how to do this. I have been unsuccessful searching Google for an answer...

Answer (score 2):

A later routine can refer to previous variable by name in a Code component. i.e. in that code component, you could insert code like this, say to update a text stimulus depending on a previous reaction time:

```
if key_resp_2.rt < 0.200:
    myTextStim.setText("Well done, quite fast.")
```

But you would need to specify what you want to do to get more specific help.
Cheers.